# (Django Simple JWT) 401 Unauthorized when logging out

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm having trouble with simple JWT when I try to log out. I'm informed that when logging out, the cookie must be deleted and the refresh token must be blacklisted!

All of the previous authentication steps (register, login) worked as expected, except for logout.

**Register**

[image]

**Login**

[image]

**Logout**

[image]

In the capture above I got 401 unauthorized. The cookie seemed to be removed as intended.

As suggested by the Q/As I found, I have tried the following:

- Print Exception but nothing showed beside 401 error.
- Add authorization header and interchange between 'Bearer ' and 'JWT '.
- Modify settings.py and apply simple jwt authentication code templates. My code is as followed:

**settings.py**

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer', 'JWT',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
]
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class LogoutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    refresh = serializers.CharField()

    default_error_messages = {
        'bad_token': _('Token is invalid or expired')
    }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        self.token = attrs['refresh']
        return attrs

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            RefreshToken(self.token).blacklist()
        except TokenError:
            self.fail('bad_token')
        except Exception as e:
            print('\nException in logging out:', e)
```

**views.py**

```py
class RegisterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

        payload = {
            # 'id': user.id,
            'email': user.email,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')

        response = Response({'message': 'success'})

        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        
        
        response.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }
        return response


class LogoutView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LogoutSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**users/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserList.as_view()),
    path('register', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('user', UserView.as_view()),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view()),
]
```

**models.py**

```py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password should not be none')
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        if user.is_superuser is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if user.is_staff is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        user.save()
        return user
    
    
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a Email')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


AUTH_PROVIDERS = {'facebook': 'facebook', 'google': 'google',
                  'twitter': 'twitter', 'email': 'email'}
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    about = models.TextField(_(
        'about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
```

The code above was derived from several tutorials but somehow did not work like they should!
Could you suggest me a way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Was you able resolve your problem? And other question, why in LoginView use ' user = CustomUser.objects.filter' instead `django.contrib.auth.authenticate()`?  This last checks password if you are using `ModelBackend`.

Comment: @Jony_23 Yes I fixed the issue on my backend. The CustomUser model was at fault

Comment: That's great! I understand, I faced many problems with custom user models.

Comment: What did you do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)` in the LogoutView.

You can safely allow logout for any user.

```
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```